# servicestack logging only DEBUG with log4net

Tags: log4net, servicestack, log4net-configuration

I can't seem to get servicestack.logging (or log4net) to log anything but DEBUG messages.
My INFO logs don't seem to work.

I have my log4net level set to ALL.

In global.asax.cs I have

```cs
LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(true); 
new AppHost().Init();
```

In my REST service class I have

```cs
private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I'll have a log entry like

```cs
_logger.InfoFormat("Get incidents request");
```

My web.config has

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

...

```xml
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\logging\\REST Service.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting "log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;" before setting the LogManager.LogFactory instance? This will tell you about any errors log4net encounters.

Comment: I was specifying the wrong LogFactory.   should have been LogManager.LogFactory = new ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetFactory(true);